# How to resolve "Trying to get property 'pros_name' of non object" in laravel?

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel-5, explode, foreach-loop-container

I have the following foreach loop in my blade which is showing error:

> trying to get property 'pros_name' of non-object

How do I resolve it?

```
@foreach ($reports as $report)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $report->room_no }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ $report->room_type }}</td>
 @if($report->book_date== null || ($report->book_date != null && ($report->release_date != null && $report->release_date < date('Y-m-d'))))
        <td class="text-danger"><strong>Vacant</strong></td>
        <td>{{ $report->price }}</td>
                                <td>---</td>
                                <td></td>
                                @endif
                                @if($report->book_date != null && ( $report->release_date ==null || $report->release_date >= date('Y-m-d')))
                                    @php 
                                        $doc = DB::table('gen_resident_room')
                                            ->Join('sales_pipeline', 'gen_resident_room.person_id', '=', 'sales_pipeline.id')
                                            ->where([['room_id',$report->room_id]])->first();
                                            $n = explode (",",$doc->pros_name); //error
                                    @endphp
                                    @if($doc->stage === "MoveIn")
                                        <td class="text-success"><b>Occupied</b></td>
                                    @else
                                        <td class="text-success"><b>Booked</b></td>
                                    @endif
                                    <td>{{ $report->price }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $doc->price }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $n[0] }} {{ $n[1] }} {{ $n[2] }}</td>
                                @endif
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

Comment: try to print $doc using print_r($doc),  whether it contains data or not?

Comment: Make sure that `$doc` actually exists and contains data

Comment: It means that ```$doc``` is not an object, which means you cannot access its values with arrow syntax. Perhaps the query that populates ```$doc``` returns an array or a boolean to signify a failed query. See what ```$doc``` contains, and what ```DB::table``` can return. (btw, doing DB lookups in the view isn't exactly ideal, I'd suggest moving this up to the controller)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to check whether the $doc contains data or not. Seems the doc is empty so its fails the script execution and throw the error.

You can validate the code also such as:

```
if(!empty($doc))
{
 // Do you stuff
}
```

or

```
if(isset($doc->pros_name)) {
     $n = explode (",",$doc->pros_name);
}
```

Comment: i did this  :                                                                                                             `if(isset($doc->pros_name)) {
     $n = explode (",",$doc->pros_name);
}`                                                                                                                                                                               however it shows a new error "trying to get property 'stage' of non-object

Comment: did you check $doc contains data or not?

Comment: if $doc has no data, then all instances regarding $doc are not able to work

Comment: yes, i checked it contains data . `dd($doc);` shows the data present.

Comment: then check stage exists or not or is there any value or empty?
you need to create another validation for stage to check empty or not

Comment: i checked in the database. there is data for stage as well.

Comment: there is data. i have checked it

Comment: so another possibility is the $doc->stage is array. try to print the code var_dump($doc->stage) and check what happens